# C# TCPClient Listen to incoming messages

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I have a TCPClient and it should listen to incoming messages from it's c&c. The messages structure should be: buffer (byte array), type(int/string), id(int) and arguments(string array).

I found this code for listening to incoming messages:

```
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
while (true)
{
    // Get a stream object for reading              
    using (NetworkStream streamFromServer = client.GetStream())
    {
        int length;
        // Read incomming stream into byte arrary.                  
        while ((length = streamFromServer.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
        {
            var incomingData = new byte[length];
            Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incomingData, 0, length);
            // Convert byte array to string message.                        
            string serverMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incomingData);
        }
    }
}
```

How I use the buffer to read the message? Also, How to convert the `incomingData` to my message structure?

Comment: Read you data from incommingData.  You do not need the serverMessage.  You can use BitConverter to extract the data.  You need to include the length of the byte array if it is variable.

Comment: If you want messaging and you're just working with TCP, it's up to *you* to do work - TCP just delivers a stream of bytes. It doesn't guarantee that each call to `Write` at one end will be matched 1-1 with calls of `Read` at the other end. Common techniques including sending the length first (but note that even such a small amount of data *could* be fragmented), using fixed size messages, or some form of delimiters. Or move to a higher level protocol *atop* TCP that does messaging for you.

Comment: If this is not just an exercise where the use of a `TcpClient` is the point, consider just using a WCF TCP endpoint, which has pretty much solved all of these problems already. You're unlikely to come up with something better out of the box.